# key: highway from pbf format file of OSM map

Tags: key, openstreetmap

I downloaded a PBF format of a region of OSM map. **Is it possible to extract the value of KEY:HIGHWAY from this file using osmosis**. The situation is I will give a location in lat/log (output of GPS) and I need to get the value of key `HIGHWAY` from the file. Is it possilbe? If anyone have the codes please provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OSM wiki has [osmosis example usages](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Example_usage). This paragraph also mentions how to extract all highways:

```
osmosis --read-xml city.osm --tf accept-ways highway=* --used-node --write-xml highways.osm
```

Don't use this approach for an interactive router. Extracting these information on the fly will be slow and inefficient. Instead do this step once (including all information relevant for [routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing), not just highway tags) and calculate a routing graph on top of these ways. Or better just use one of the existing [end user routing softwares](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing#End_users:_Routing_software) for OSM.